# AJAX save JSON array into multiple JS variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to get multiple Values from a mySQL Query and save it into multiple JS Variables.

This is my JS file with my AJAX Code:

```
 $.ajax({
        async:false,
        url: "get_data.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            d1: 'd1',a1: 'a1'
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(data));

        }
    });
```

With **$("#result").text(JSON.stringify(data));** i get this Result:

> [{"d1":"2","a1":"3"}]

Now I want to save each Value into separate JS Variables (e.g: d1 into **var default**; a1 into **var second**)

How can i save my Values in seperate JS Variables?

Comment: `default=data[0].d1;`

Comment: THX Satpal. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

See this

```js
var data = '[{"d1":"2","a1":"3"}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(obj[0]);

document.write("d1 = " + obj[0].d1);
document.write(" // ");
document.write("a1 = " + obj[0].a1);
```

Write this code in `success` of your `$.ajax`.

Comment: This is the solution I use:  success: function (data) {d1 = (data[0].d1);a1 = (data[0].a1);} Now I can use d1 and a1 as JS variables.